Question about partial differential equation, $(3x^2+1)u_t+2tu_x=0$
I am to solve the equation
$(3x^2 + 1 ) u_t+2tu_x=0$ with the condition $u(x,0) = e^{-x^2}$ using the method of characteristics. This is what I have found so far,
We have $dt/ds=3x^2+1$, $dx/ds=2t$ and $du/ds=0$, so the equation is constant along the base characteristic curves. The first two give
$\frac{dx/ds}{dt/ds} = \frac{2t}{3x^2+1} \Longrightarrow \int (3x^2+1)dx = \int 2t dt\Longrightarrow x^3+x=t^2 + C_1$
where $C_1$ is a constant of integration.
Since $du/ds=0$, $u(x,t)=G(C_1)=G(x^3+x-t^2)$ for some arbritrary function $G$. The initial conditions give
$
G(x,0)=G(x^3+x)=e^{-x^2}.
$
Is this correct? How do I continue from here?

$$(3x^2 + 1 ) u_t+2tu_x=0$$
The general solution of the PDE is :
$$u(x,t)=G(x^3+x-t^2)\tag1$$
with arbitrary function $G$.
Or equivalently
$$x^3+x-t^2=F(u)\tag2$$
with arbitrary function $F$.
Condition $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$
It is simpler to use the form $(2)$
$$x^3+x=F(e^{-x^2})$$
Let $X=e^{-x^2}\quad\implies\quad x=\pm\sqrt{-\ln(X)}$
$$F(X)=\pm\left((-\ln(X))^{3/2}+(-\ln(X))^{1/2} \right)$$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the equation $(2)$ where th argument is $X=u$
$$\boxed{x^3+x-t^2=\pm\left((-\ln(u))^{3/2}+(-\ln(u))^{1/2} \right)} \tag3$$
This is the solution expressed on implicit form which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.
In order to express the solution on explicit form one have to solve Eq.$(3)$ for $u$. This involves solving a polynomial equation of third degree.
If the problem is an academic problem the calculus appears too complicated. Are you sure that there is not a typo in the wording ?
